# Formal version of "as and when needed"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is there any formal version of "as and when needed" for written English?

Comment: What is not formal about that construct?

Comment: In fact, I wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine for formal writing as it is. Another phrase which means the same is *if and when necessary*.